# Why doesn't the if statement recognise that the int == 0?

Tags: python

I'm creating a text based adventure game, and this is meant to be a small fight. The `int`s `userhits` or `deputyhits` should be set to `0` at some point, but the code is stuck in a loop that goes passed `0`.

```
def deputyfight(deputyawake):
     print("You do not have any weapons, you will have to fight him.")
     userhits = 5
     deputyhits = 5
     print("You run at the guard and throw a punch at him")
     print("He dodges it, the fight has begun")
     loop = True
     while loop:
        if loop:
            userdmg = int(random.randint(5, 10))
            deputydmg = int(random.randint(1, 10))
            if userdmg >= deputydmg:
                print("You punch the deputy")
                userhits -= 1
                print(userhits)
            elif userhits == 0:
                print("You knock out the deputy and drag him into the cell")
                print("He is out cold, he most likely won't remember this or
                you")
                deputyawake = False
                sheriffsoffice(deputyawake)
            elif deputydmg < userdmg:
                print("The deputy punches you")
                usershealth(5)
                deputyhits -= 1
                print(deputyhits)
            elif deputyhits == 0:
                print("The deputy puts up a good fight, but you catch him with a
                lucky punch")
                print("You win the fight, but have taken a lot of damage")
                print("Your health is at: ", health)
                deputyawake = False
                sheriffsoffice(deputyawake)
```

Comment: where do you set your `loop` to `False` or `break`? seems it's an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Currently your `while` loop will go on forever since you set it to `True` initially, then never alter the `loop` value you are using in the `while` to `False`. Inside your loop you will have to have some condition check like this:

```
if deputyhits or userhits == 0:
    loop = False
    # alternatively you can just break here
```

If you set it to `False` like so, the next iteration of your `while` will check if `loop = True`, and since it's now `False`, the `while` will not execute again. A [`break`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm) can also be used, but keep in mind that once a `break` is executed, any remaining code that has not been executed in that iteration of the `while` will not be executed.

Comment: @Daniel: Python's own [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) also has a good explanation of what `break` does.